Terminology for types of errors and uncertainty: intrinsic? fitting?
Say I have a sequence of given variables $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ and the response $y_i$ and we explore the model $y_i\sim \text{Normal}(\alpha x_i,\sigma^2)$ with $y_i$ independent of $y_j$ for $i\neq j$.
Parameters $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ we fit using maximum likelihood.
Say we wish to forecast $y_n$ given $x_n$. It seems clear that the best forecast on $y_n$ would be $\alpha_\text{MLE}\,x_n$. There are at least two types of uncertainties as far as I can see:

An uncertainty intrinsic to the model, that is, $\sigma$. We cannot hope to predict $y_n$ with a better precision than $\sigma$, which is akin to an "observational error".
An uncertainty derived from the fact that the MLE estimators have a variance given by the expected Fisher information, related with the second derivative or curvature of the likelihood function at maximum. This is what colloquially can be called the "fitting error/uncertainty" of $\alpha_\text{MLE}$. Certainly, this "error" is propagated to the best estimator for $y_n$, creating another source of uncertainty.

What standard terminology is used for these two types of uncertainty?

"Proper" may be tricky (who is the arbiter of propriety of terminology?); I've seen multiple distinct terms used for each of those sources of uncertainty (and there are other sources of uncertainty as well) so, depending on how you view the framing of the question, it may either have no correct answer or multiple correct answers.

Thank you. References to source material is appreciated as well.

The comment was intended as a suggestion to clarify "proper" in a way that made the question more specific / more readily answerable.

Ok, changed "the proper" for just "standard"
